# Adding minutes (time) to date

Tags: php, date, yii

I am storing appointments by adding 15 minutes to current date as default appointment duration and trying to add Minutes to a date obtained by following code:

```
$curr_date=new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));--Obtained the current date and time.
$curr_date->add(new DateInterval('P15M'));--Adding 15 minutes
```

But when I save the Model it throws error saying:

> Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To add 15 minutes you can use new DateTime("+15 minutes");

Comment: P15M would be 15 month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to format the date so the SQL query if generated the right way. Use [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) when you put value into your model.

```
$my_model->myattribute = $curr_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks. The error is gone but 15 minutes are not added...any clues...?

Comment: Got it. The "T" was missing. Correct code to add is: $curr_date->add(new DateInterval('PT15M'));